# How to edit multilevel list in Word 2011 Mac

Tags: microsoft-word, office-for-mac, microsoft-word-2011

I use the multilevel list feature in Word [as described here](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) to set up proper nested numbering linked to styles. I did this on Windows, and it worked well.

Now I am editing the documents on my Mac using Word 2011. I need to modify the list style; I can create  a new multi-level list style from the toolbar dropdown, but I can't right-click to edit an existing one. How can I edit my existing list style on Word for Mac?

Thanks

Comment: See John Korchock's page https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/ which shows these procedures on the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

- Open the menu "format"
- Select "Bullets and numbering"
- Select the "list styles" tab

Your style should be visible in the list on the left. You can select it and click the button labelled "Modify..." on the right. To go deeper and modify the numbering scheme, click the Format dropdown, Numbering, then Customize and you will be back at the Customize Outline Numbered list dialog.

[image: Format > Bullets & Numbering > List Styles > Modify > Format > Numbering > Customize]

Comment: I can confirm this leads to the same dialog pictured in the ShaunaKelly.com instructions OP linked to.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.